# Replace Compile Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I'm having trouble compiling my code

```
Dim OriginalText As String
Dim CorrectedText As String

OriginalText = Range("A5").Value

CorrectedText = Replace(OriginalText, "a", "o")

Range("A5").Offset(, 1).Value = CorrectedText
```

In Cell A5 I have the word Micrasaft and I want to replace with Microsoft.

I get 'Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment'.

---

I know why, because I called my Sub Replace, didn't know that if you name your sub the same way a formula, it won't compile

Comment: any more code to it? Oh btw. You can achieve the same result with one line of code: `Range("A5").Offset(0, 1).Value = Replace(Range("A5"), "a", "o")`

Comment: Same problem, I'm still getting the compile error with your formula, and I eliminated all the declared variables, don't know why I'm getting this error

Comment: Is this all the code? Where is it located? What is the name of this procedure? Does it take any parameters?

Comment: What is `.Offset(, 1)`?

Comment: I reckon you've got another function/variable that you called `Replace` somewhere in your code. Does it work if you change it to use `VBA.Replace`?

Comment: Means that I'll only move one column and I'm not moving from row

Comment: If that is really all the code, it compiles and runs fine on my machine. Rory's question is a plausible cause. Be sure to check all modules.

Comment: I used VBA.Replace() in my original code and it worked. Why do sometimes VBA compiles without using VBA.Formula and in this especif case I had to use it?

Comment: The code above looks fine. There must be something you haven't told us that is causing the problem.

Range("A5").Offset(, 1).Value is the same as Range("A5").Offset(0, 1).Value and deposits the response in cell B5 (in the example above).

Comment: I know why, because I called my Sub Replace, didn't know that if you name your sub the same way a formula, it won't compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following way:

```
Dim OriginalText As String
Dim CorrectedText As String

OriginalText = Range("A5").Value

CorrectedText = VBA.Strings.Replace(OriginalText, "a", "o")

Range("A5").Offset(, 1).Value = CorrectedText
```